# Enable/Disable dragging of marker on google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to enable dragging with the button "Enable" and disable dragging with the button "Disable" in my google maps code. I tried with this code after the creation of each marker:

```
function Disable() {
      marker.disableDragging();}
 function Enable() {
      marker.enableDragging();
    }
```

But it doesn't work, and i don't know why. I think that code is correct, but what is wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the code is correct?  `Marker.disableDragging` and `Marker.enableDragging` are [Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info) methods, are you using that version of the API?  What javascript errors are you getting? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You should use

for disabling draggable on map

```
map.setOptions({draggable: true});
```

or

```
map.setOptions({draggable: false});
```

and for disable/enable single marker  you should use

```
marker.setDraggable(false);
```

or

```
marker.setDraggable(true);
```

if you want do this for all markers you should iterate over the entire collection of markers

Comment: Your answer is a bit misleading. map.setOptions({draggable: false}) prevents dragging of map ITSELF not ALL MARKERS.

Comment: My answer explain both for map and for single marker .. the firts disable  draggable on the map   the second  for the single marker .. seems clear ..

Comment: Well, you said 'You should use for all markers' map.setOptions({draggable: false});' You state that the command would disable dragging for all markers. But it doesn't do that, it disabled dragging of whole map. That's two different things. Anyway, just suggesting improvement, might be confusing to some users.

Comment: @MatejP.  i have update the answer ..

Comment: When I create a marker i set draggable;true. It is a problem?

Comment: NO you can change the "draggable" when you need .. but for this you must have the marker object available .. or you can set to false draggable for the map.. so any markers (or others ) object is draggable .